# Test with ADT exercise

Tags: java, eclipse

Hi all i'm making a simple exercise with stack ADT. I must return an inverted string using just a stack. That's the code I made:

```
public class StackInvertTEST {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner tr = new Scanner(System.in);
        String temp=tr.next();
        System.out.println(invert(temp));
    }


static <E> String invert(String str){
    Stack<String> stack = new ArrayStack<String>();
    String temp="";
    while(!str.isEmpty()){
        stack.push(str);
    }
    while(!stack.isEmpty()){
        temp=stack.pop();
    }
    return temp;
    }
}
```

it wont work. It just doesn't return anything. Any suggestion? Thank you.

Comment: Well, your logic is wrong. What do you expect the first `while` loop to do? Your code doesn't have any of the character handling required for the task.

Comment: Use the stack to store Character objects, not Strings. Get the Character objects from the String's internal char array

Comment: Exactly. I solved using a stack of Char then using toString to push into the stack. Thank you.